# EA origin on the house games should be downloaded or just added to account?

Tags: origin

Ea origin offers a free game every month and from what I hear you get to keep the game forever. My questions are:

1. In order to have the game, you need to install it or just add it to your account?
2. What happens when you format your HDD or uninstall a game due to lack of space and want to re-install it later?
3. If a game also exists on steam, is there a way to connect them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the free game to your account the download starts automatically. You can't prevent that, but you can cancel it while it downloads. You don't need to finish the download and install it, it will stay in your account.

If you want to install a game later, you can just download it again.

There is no way to connect Origin to steam games.

Comment: So if I cancell it as soon as it starts, I still have the game forever?

Comment: That's right, it will stay in your library.